# Changing Theme does not effect launch screen

Tags: android, xml

I can successfully swap theme onCreate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Read from database and get theme
    ...........
    if ( setup.getSelectedTheme() == Setup.SelectedTheme.SELECTED_THEME_DARK ) {
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Also I have a `launch_screen.xml` which only shows at startup.

**launch_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Splash Screen Background (Color/Image) -->
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorSelectedBackgroundColor" />
</layer-list>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorSelectedBackgroundColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorSelectedBackgroundColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

`colorSelectedBackgroundColor` is white at `AppTheme` or black at `DarkTheme`. I want the screen to be black or white at the beginning according to the selected theme. But this code not working.

What should I do?

Comment: I didn't see the edited post but bellow answer should still help. Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: @Alex I already did like the answer and it didn't work.

Comment: Are you talking about a white flash when the app starts? And the theme then swaps about a second later?

Comment: @CharlesAnnic Simply I want to make black flash if the dark theme is enabled. Yes  the theme then swaps about a second later

Comment: White flash should not appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own version of DarkTheme and WhiteTheme in styles.xml:

```
  <style name="DarkTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
    </style>

  <style name="WhiteTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

And then use it in your code:

```
 if ( setup.getSelectedTheme() == Setup.SelectedTheme.SELECTED_THEME_DARK ) {
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
    } else {
        setTheme(R.style.WhiteTheme);
    }
```

Good luck!

Edit 1:

You can also just make 2 versions of launch_screen.xml. One is launch_screen_white.xml and the other launch_screen_black.xml.

launch_screen_white.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Splash Screen Background (Color/Image) -->
    <item "android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
</layer-list>
```

launch_screen_black.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Splash Screen Background (Color/Image) -->
    <item "android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
</layer-list>
```

And then change the background of your parent view with these based on

```
 if ( setup.getSelectedTheme() == Setup.SelectedTheme.SELECTED_THEME_DARK )
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you expect, but unfortunately the theme swap takes place about a second after the application is launched and there is nothing you can do about it. There will always be a flash before the theme changes.

However, if you only want to switch between a light and a dark theme, you can use `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight` as a parent for your light and dark themes, and add a theme with no custom background as the main theme.

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    </style>
    <style name="Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorSelectedBackgroundColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorSelectedBackgroundColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The theme swap would therefore be done programmatically in this way:

```
if(setup.getSelectedTheme() == Setup.SelectedTheme.SELECTED_THEME_DARK) {
    setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
} else {
    setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
}
```

However, the choice between the light and dark theme is made according to the system settings and not those of the application.

Notes that the background color of the dark theme is not equal to `#00000000`, it is a dark grey. However, the flash will be less annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost been 2 years but here you go.
Just have an empty Activity before loading the activity_main.

Create a class file in com.example.MyApplication (where MainActivity.kt is)

`DarkThemeActivity.kt`

```
class DarkThemeApplication : Application() {
    private val mainPrefInstance by lazy { getSharedPreferences("main", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val themePref = mainPrefInstance.getString("Theme", ThemeHelper.DEFAULT_MODE)!!
        ThemeHelper.applyTheme(themePref)
        // I'm using shared preference to save my theme but you can replace 
        // the last two lines with however you want to set theme
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".DarkThemeApplication"
    .
    .
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

This will load the theme so the correct theme will be used in the splash screen too.

Note: If you are wondering how `ThemeHelper` is implemented, here you go.

```
object ThemeHelper {
    const val LIGHT_MODE = "light"
    const val DARK_MODE = "dark"
    const val DEFAULT_MODE = "default"


    fun applyTheme(themePref: String, isDarkThemeOn: Boolean = false) {
        when (themePref) {
            LIGHT_MODE -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            }
            DARK_MODE -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            }
            DEFAULT_MODE -> {
                if (isDarkThemeOn) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

An demo application is available in [Android's Github page](https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/DarkTheme) (android/user-interface-samples)